# How can I tell querydsl-maven-plugin to generate NumberPath with Long instead of BigDecimal?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, querydsl

I am using `querydsl-maven-plugin` in order to export Q paths from an Oracle 11g database. The problem I am facing is that Oracle `NUMBER` fields are mapped to   `NumberPath<java.math.BigDecimal>` instead of `NumberPath<Long>`

Is there any way I can instruct `querydsl-maven-plugin` to translate `BigDecimal` to `Long` during code generation?

The approach I am taking right now is to use the plugin to generate the code and then translate types by hand.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently possible to declare custom user types in the configuration of the querydsl-maven-plugin like this

```
<configuration>
  <customTypes>
    <customType>com.example.NumericLongType</customType>
  </customTypes>
</configuration>
```

com.example.NumericLongType would need to implement the com.mysema.query.sql.types.Type interface

But ideally this should be something like this

```
<configuration>
  <overrides>
    <NUMERIC>java.lang.Long</NUMERIC>
  </overrides>
</configuration>
```

and Querydsl would handle the mapping from NUMERIC to Long internally.

Feel free to open a ticket for it.

**Update**

Numeric mappings are now customizable in Querydsl https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/273

Comment: is there documentation available on how to configure this?

Comment: You can rely on the default mappings which are mentioned in the issue or add overrides via this configuration method http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.9.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/sql/Configuration.html#registerNumeric%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: thanks, I was digging through the queryDSL code and found this too. Is it possible to do this via maven config? Just curious, as I think I will be using MappingProjection<ModelClass) and can perform the type mapping in there. BTW, thanks for queryDSL, impressive.

Comment: For the moment this is not yet supported in the Maven config, but can be added